# Proof by contradiction in Game Theory: is this paper correct?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, game-theory, reference-works

I have doubts whether [this](https://mpra.ub.uni-muenchen.de/75876/1/MPRA_paper_66637.pdf)
paper is sound and correct in its very basic setting. It discusses the relationship between $\varphi\vdash\psi$ and $\varphi\Rightarrow\psi$ and denies it in general, i.e. whenever $\varphi$ and $\psi$ might not be true. The paper goes a bit beyond what I (and as the author points out, many other researchers) generally trust (and use) about logic in connection with game theory. *I'm also interested in a summary on what it really says beyond what I have just put in the body of this question.*

I'm interested this in connection with the Maschler's bargaining set $\cal M$. It is a set defined by boolean combinations of linear inequalities, and I believe it goes like this: $x\in \cal M$ if there is no justified objection at $x$. I have obtained by this reasoning $x\in{\cal M} \Longleftrightarrow x\in X \land A\Longrightarrow B$ where the statement $A$ says that there is a objection at $x$ and $B$ that there is a counterobjection at $x$.

Now the author claims this is not sound and that it should read $x\in{\cal M} \Longleftrightarrow x\in X \land A\land B.$ This is very weird for me, anyone agrees with the author ?

Comment: The paper in question looks quite confused to me.

Comment: @AndreasBlass Thank you for your opinion, that's what I expected to hear.

Comment: Interestingly, I think this (utter nonsense) paper was asked about on MSE a few months ago, for the same reason. ([Searching](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=url%3Ahttps%3A%2F%2Fmpra.ub.uni-muenchen.de%2F) indicates that either I'm mistaken or that previous question was deleted, fwiw.)

Comment: @AndreasBlass You should post that as an answer, so that this question can get resolved.

Comment: @NoahSchweber I have a good reason to resolving my question: it shook the very basic reasoning from my master thesis from the year 2000. But it is in the Czech language so nobody would be interested reading it.

Comment: @NoahSchweber Done.

Comment: For what it's worth, this paper does not appear to have been peer reviewed in any way; it is hosted on what is simply a repository for unpublished papers. There is no particular reason to give it any more credence than a blog post or internet comment.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The paper in question looks quite confused to me.

Answer (score -4):

By virtue of the authority granted to them by StackExchange, some members declare the Discussion Paper [MPRA Paper 66637](https://mpra.ub.uni-muenchen.de/75876/1/MPRA_paper_66637.pdf) as "confusing" or "utter nonsense" without answering the underlying question of how one should conduct a clean proof by contradiction based on the Deduction Theorem when the provability or deducibility of the clauses $\phi$ and $\varphi$ are assumed in order to establish that $\phi \vdash \varphi$ is provable/deducible. How can one assure under these circumstances that $\phi$ and $\varphi$ are consistent and logically independent clauses, and that this leads to a correct logical conclusion within a model? How can we avoid the Principle of Explosion also subsumed under "ex falso sequitur quodlibet",~i.e., from falsehood anything follows? I am wondering what is on this line of reasoning "confusing" or "utter nonsense"?

The answer of @Andreas Blass as well as the comments fail to explain these crucial issues. I invite those members to provide the answer. As long as they could not succeed, I regard my objections against this proof technique as not refuted.

Comment: Which implication do you think doesn't hold in general $\Leftarrow$ or $\Rightarrow$: $$(\varphi\vdash\psi) \Longleftrightarrow (\varphi\Rightarrow\psi)$$ ?

Comment: Please consult the paper: https://arxiv.org/abs/1908.00409. This will answer your question.

Comment: I think that you claim in your paper only $$(\varphi\vdash \psi)\Longrightarrow (\varphi\Rightarrow \psi),$$ is not correct, is that right ?

Comment: I say, one needs to establish that the clauses $\phi$ and $\varphi$ are provable/deducible in order to show that $\phi \vdash \varphi$ is provable/deducible, and that therefore $\phi \Rightarrow \varphi$ is provable/deducible as well. Hence, we are not allowed to assume that the clause $\phi$ or $\varphi$ is provable/deducible.

Comment: If $\varphi$ is provable then always $\psi\Rightarrow\varphi$, do you agree ?

Comment: No! I am pretty clear with that in the mentioned paper above. Please consult it again.

Comment: The paper is unreadable by me and others due to logical skips.

Comment: If $\varphi$ is provable from $\psi$ and $\psi$ holds in the model then $\varphi$ holds there.

Comment: I do not think so! You well understood the point! But it is not the result you want to have.

Comment: OK. But you are repeatedly repeat your stuff from the paper without making anyone besides you understand it.

Comment: Certainly not! My arguments were well understood from the community. From my side, everything is told. Now, I am waiting for a profound response with regard to my invitation. In the meantime, you have to ask somebody else.